# ASP.NET Web service caching model guidance

Tags: asp.net, mono

I am creating a set of ASP.NET web services that each method is required to pass an authentication key.  This authentication key is used to:

1. Validate this client application/user is licensed.
2. Get customer specific connection information (mysql connect, socket connect) to point at a particular server.
3. Individual preferences (such as default store, system user, etc)

I'd like to keep the data in a MySql database where the web services are hosted.  Clearly I can do the required validations/priming by reading the database, but I'd like to cache this information so that I don't have to round-trip to the database on every service request.

Can someone point me at the appropriate model in ASP.Net to solve this?

Comment: If you're using the key for authentication, then you may not want to cache the authentication decision. That way, as soon as a user is removed from the system, the web service will become useless to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class, here is the [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx).